# Primefaces p:fileUpload auto upload doesn't show the cancel option for invalid file

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Environment
JSF 2.0, Primefaces 3.4.2

File upload code is as below

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{myBean.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" update="messages11" auto="true" sizeLimit="1000000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" rendered="#{myBean.fileUploadRendered}" ></p:fileUpload>
```

If I upload any invalid format then error message displays correctly that Invalid File type but after message it doesn't show the cancel option as shown in the example [here](http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadAuto.jsf). If I add correct format then It does get uploaded and I can access that file in myBean.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

try to close the tag directly

```
<p:fileUpload
    fileUploadListener="#{myBean.handleFileUpload}"
    mode="advanced"
    update="messages11"
    auto="true"
    sizeLimit="1000000"
    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
    rendered="#{myBean.fileUploadRendered}" />
```

that is the only difference you have to the showcase example

Comment: closing tag directly doesn't solve the problem. I did it and problem is still there

Comment: do you have a form around the fileupload?

Comment: I tried it with this params in my actual project and it works as desired. Did you change something in the CSS? did you try to assign the file in the bean with value in the fileUpload tag?

Comment: I didn't change CSS anywhere. I did try assigning the value in fileUpload tag but still facing the same problem. I know it is not browser issue because with same browser example (mentions is the question) works fine

Comment: try updating your JSF implementation to a newer version. maybe this helps. because the example works in my Jboss 7 as desired.

Answer (score -1):

use `auto="false"` and shoud solve your problem.

Comment: Disabling this contradicts the title of the question.